# Telerik grid: retrieve row count with Ajax binding

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, telerik

how can I access grid row count with Ajax binding in Telerik ASP.Net MVC grid?
I need to display total in a footer, see code snippet below.   The total has to update on insert and delete.

With server binding, there is @Model.Count().  How can I do the same thing with Ajax binding?

thank you!

```
    @{
    Html.Telerik()
        .Grid<ContractMonth>()
        .Name("contractMonthGrid")
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
            .Ajax()
            .Select("_AjaxBinding", "ContractMonth")
            .Insert("_AjaxInsert", "ContractMonth")
            .Delete("_AjaxDelete", "ContractMonth")
            )
        .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.Id))
        .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.StartDate).EditorTemplateName("Date").FooterTemplate(@<text>@Model.Count()</text>);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Telerik MVC grid supports server and [Ajax aggregates](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/aggregatesajax):

> The following aggregates are supported:
>
> - Average
> - Count
> - Min
> - Max
> - Sum
>
> To specify the aggregates for a column use the Aggregates method

So in your sample:

```
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.StartDate)
               .EditorTemplateName("Date")
               .Aggregate(aggregates => aggregates.Count())
               .FooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Count</text>)
               .ClientFooterTemplate("<#= Count #>");
    }
```

If you need the row count "outside" the grid you can use the grid's [client side API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var totalRows = $("#contractMonthGrid").data("tGrid").total;
    //do something with totalRows 
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for the code, and the link to Ajax aggregates documentation!